# How do I take input from the user of their full name, and then output their first name and last name seperately? (C++)

Tags: c++

I only so far made the outline, and I just don't know how to continue onwards with it, I am stumped.

Example output should be:

- enter your full name

- xfdgchkv loyloyloy

- your name is xfdgchkv and surname is loyloyloy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()  {
    string fullName;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    cout << "please input your full name, specifying only your last and first name" << endl;
    cin >> fullName;
    fullName = firstName + lastName;
```

Comment: Pleaest try splitting the captured data by a space.

Comment: Can you write an example of input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin` ignore space/new-line, so you can use this:

```
cin >> firstname >> lastname;
```